# How to fill attribute of xslt from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add the value of xml into attribute of xslt. Tried various solutions but none is working. Refer below XML and corresponding XSLT code.

XML:

```
    <root>
    <orderNo>123</orderNo>
    </root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:read="http:/xxxxxx" 
          xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
          <read:Shipment 
            orderNo="<xsl:select="/jsonToXML[@orderNo]"/>" 
            ShipNode="?">
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tried various solutions but none is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)...

```
<read:Shipment orderNo="{root/orderNo}" ShipNode="?"/>
```

Also notice that the XPath in the AVT has changed. There is no `jsonToXML` element and `orderNo` is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: :: <read:Shipment ShipNode="?" orderNo="{/jsonToXML[@orderNo]}"> is returning me blank value.

Comment: @ChetanPotdar - You might not have seen my edit. Your xpath needs to change.

Comment: Working now... Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried -

```
<xsl:value-of select="name/@orderNo" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit but i am getting error as "Unable to save: The XSL is missing or invalid. The value of attribute "orderNo" associated with an element type "read:Shipment" must not contain the '<' character."

Comment: This does not work as you cannot have an `xsl:value-of` inside an attribute (the double quotes of the `select=` mess with the double quotes of the attribute).